# extract only a subfolder from a zip file without the path

Tags: command-line, unzip

I have a little problem!
I have a zip file "Backup.zip"; in this zipfile I have: `/Users/USERNAME/Pictures`

The Picture directory has files and directories.

I need to extract only the Picture folder but without `/Users/USERNAME/`.

I have tried:

```
unzip Backup.zip '/Users/USERNAME/Pictures/*' -d home/USERNAME/Pictures/
```

and

```
unzip Backup.zip '/Users/USERNAME/Pictures/' -d home/USERNAME/Pictures/
```

and

```
unzip Backup.zip -d home/USERNAME/Pictures/ '/Users/USERNAME/Pictures/*'
```

But I become `home/USERNAME/Pictures/Users/USERNAME/Pictures`.

What is my mistake?

Comment: is it because you are adding a `/` at the end of the command?

Comment: unzip Backup.zip '/Users/USERNAME/Pictures/' -d home/USERNAME/Pictures its the same

Comment: Perhaps you want the `-j` option? See for example [Junk a part of the directory with unzip?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85797/junk-a-part-of-the-directory-with-unzip)

Comment: The problem seems to be that with the option -j all folders are irgnored even those that I actually want to keep!
Seems like I have to unzip it and then move it with mv ... very sad

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that [steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver) is on the right path with [unzip's "-j junk paths" option](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/man1/unzip.1.html):

```
cd /target/destination/for/Pictures
unzip -j /path/to/backup.zip 'home/USERNAME/Pictures/*'
```

This tells `unzip` to extract files matching the pattern `home/USERNAME/Pictures/*` (safely quoted from the shell, just in case) from the zip file and to strip out the leading directory paths as it does so. Be careful to use the same extraction pattern as exists in the zip file.